# Is edit review working as it should for user >2K rep?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

User >2K rep can edit Q & A and edits apply immediately, from [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> We believe in the power of community editing. That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit anything in the system without it going through peer review.

However if user >2K rep **approves** edit that edit still needs approval from other reviewers to be applied. For example my approval in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54474567/6413377).

It is not a big deal but I am just wondering the difference: I could have done the same edit and have it applied instantaneously but when I approve someone others edit it needs more reviews?

In other words how come SO trusts my edits but not my reviews? What would be the problem if >2K user could instantaneously approve edit?

Comment: robo reviewers would simply approve all sorts of rubbish singlehandedly. This question comes up a lot.

Comment: Do note that SE recently moved the amount of reviewers required for an edit from 3 to 2. Also (often) if an edit is essential (e.g. horrible and unreadable formatting, corrected in an edit) I often make a minor change and instantly approve the edit via _Improve and edit_.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm pretty sure only SO had the 3-reviewer requirement.